# How do you use a function as a parameter in a function?

Tags: python, function, parameters

I am trying to use a function as a parameter in another function but I keep getting an error. Can you guys please take a look at my code.

```
#Program used to reverse the order of a string.

sentence = input("Write a sentence. After you click enter it will be returned in reverse order. ")
userInputList = [ ]
reverseInputList = [ ]

#remove any periods from the sentence.
def remove(sentence):
  stripped = sentence.replace(".", "")
  return stripped

#print string in reverse order
def convertList(stripped):
  userInputList = stripped.split()
  reverseInputList = userInputList[::-1]

  for i in range(len(reverseInputList)):
   print (reverseInputList[i], end=" ")


remove(sentence)

convertList(remove())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know want error you get but I see mistake:

you have to assign result from `remove(sentence)` to variable and use this result in `convertList()`

```
result = remove(sentence)

convertList(result)
```

or you have to use function with argument `remove(sentence)` directly in `convertList()`

```
convertList(remove(sentence))
```